# Filter and get list of remote file names from Sftp

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I need to get list of remote file names from sftp server whose modified time is more than some given time and then delete all those files from sftp, I'm using `SftpOutboundGateway`'s `NLST` command to list the file names

But it gets all files from the given remote dir path, I tried `.filter(lastModifiedFileListFilter)` that didn't work then I also tried `.filterFunction(logicGiven)` didn't work either

I wonder if `NLST` command support filtering

Here is the code sample:

Filter instance:

```
private FileListFilter lastModifiedFilter(){
    LastModifiedFileListFilter fileListFilter = new LastModifiedFileListFilter();
    fileListFilter.setAge(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return fileListFilter;
}
```

With filter() method:

```
  @Bean
public IntegrationFlow deleteFiles(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.channel.bulk-delete")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.NLST,"headers[path]")
                    .filter(lastModifiedFilter()))
            .get();
```

with filterFunction() method:

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow deleteFiles(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.channel.bulk-delete")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.NLST,"headers[path]")
                    .filterFunction(file->{
                        Instant decidedTime = Instant.now().minus(120, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
                       return Instant.ofEpochSecond(file.getAttrs().getMTime()).isBefore(decidedTime);
                    }))
            .log()
            .get();
```

How can I filter and get file names. I dont want to use mget command

**UPDATE**

The RM command in the next handle method doesn't delete, I also placed a break point in `doRm()` method it doesn't stop there though I have files in my for loop

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow deleteFiles(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.channel.bulk-delete")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS,"headers[path]")
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY)
                    .filterFunction(file->{
                        Instant decidedTime = Instant.now().minus(120, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
                        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(file.getAttrs().getMTime()).isBefore(decidedTime);
                    }))
            .log()
            .handle(fileList->{
                List<String> files = (List<String>) fileList.getPayload();
                for (String remoteFile: files) {
                    Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
                            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.RM,
                            "headers[file_remoteDirectory]+"+remoteFile);
                }
            })
            .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLST only fetches the file names so there is no timestamp to filter on.

NLST currently applies no filters at all.

Use LS (possibly with the recursive `-R` option).

Comment: Thanks. I have already fixed the issue with LS, But down the line I have RM command to delete the listed files, RM command doesn't delete any file. Can you please point out what mistake I'm doing, I have updated my question

Comment: I don't see how any of that can work, `NAME_ONLY` returns a list of String, not a list of `LsEntry`. Your remove logic is completely wrong, you are simply creating a new outbound gateway spec for each file name, not sending anything to them; you need to add a `.split()` and then `handle(Sftp..)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I wasn't having much idea about splitter until you mentioned, only I had to do is let `DefaultMessageSplitter` do its job. You guys are great thanks again